# How to solve org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.Text

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to analyze a retail store data where i want to solve the breakdown of sales by city ,Here is my data

```
Date       Time   City        Product-Cat      Sale-Value Payment-Mode
2012-01-01 09:20  Fort Worth  Women's Clothing 153.57     Visa
2012-01-01 09:00  San Jose    Mens Clothing    214.05     Rupee
2012-01-01 09:00  San Diego   Music            76.43      Amex
2012-01-01 09:00  New York    Cameras           45.76     Visa
```

Now i want to calculate sales break down by product category across all the stores

Here is the Mapper and reducer and the main class

```
public class RetailDataAnalysis {

public static class RetailDataAnalysisMapper extends Mapper<Text,Text,Text,Text>{

   // when trying with LongWritable Key 
    public void map(LongWritable key,Text Value,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

        String analyser [] = Value.toString().split(",");
        Text productCategory = new Text(analyser[3]);
        Text salesPrice = new Text(analyser[4]);
        context.write(productCategory, salesPrice);
    }

 // When trying with Text key

    public void map(Text key,Text Value,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

        String analyser [] = Value.toString().split(",");
        Text productCategory = new Text(analyser[3]);
        Text salesPrice = new Text(analyser[4]);
        context.write(productCategory, salesPrice);
    }


}


public static class RetailDataAnalysisReducer extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text>{

    protected void reduce(Text key,Iterable<Text> values,Context context)throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        String csv ="";
        for(Text value:values){

            if(csv.length()>0){
                csv+= ",";
            }
            csv+=value.toString();
        }
        context.write(key, new Text(csv));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf =  new  Configuration();
    String [] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf,args).getRemainingArgs();
    if(otherArgs.length<2){
        System.out.println("Usage Retail Data ");
        System.exit(2);
    }
    Job job= new Job(conf,"Retail Data Analysis");
    job.setJarByClass(RetailDataAnalysis.class);
    job.setMapperClass(RetailDataAnalysisMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(RetailDataAnalysisReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(RetailDataAnalysisReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    for(int i=0;i<otherArgs.length-1;++i){
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[i]));
    }
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[otherArgs.length-1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true)?0:1);
  }
}
```

And the exception i am getting is when using LongWritable Key,

```
   18/04/11 09:15:40 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1523355254827_0008_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
  Error: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1069)
```

Exception i am getting when trying to use Text key

```
   Error: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1069)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:712)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.map(Mapper.java:124)
```

Please help me to solve this,i am very new to hadoop.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea of this ?? Please help thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You may need different input format class. By default used is [TextInputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/TextInputFormat.html) which split the file line by line and gives line number as `LongWritable` and the line as `Text`.

You can specify the input format class this way:

```
job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
```

In your case, if you do not need the key, just the values, you can use `LongWritable` as key:

```
public static class RetailDataAnalysisMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text Value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        //...
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Here is whole code after modyfing to use `LongWritable` as key:

```
public class RetailDataAnalysis {

    public static class RetailDataAnalysisMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text Value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String analyser[] = Value.toString().split(",");
            Text productCategory = new Text(analyser[3]);
            Text salesPrice = new Text(analyser[4]);
            context.write(productCategory, salesPrice);
        }
    }

    public static class RetailDataAnalysisReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

        protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String csv = "";
            for (Text value : values) {
                if (csv.length() > 0) {
                    csv += ",";
                }
                csv += value.toString();
            }
            context.write(key, new Text(csv));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
        if (otherArgs.length < 2) {
            System.out.println("Usage Retail Data ");
            System.exit(2);
        }
        Job job = new Job(conf, "Retail Data Analysis");
        job.setJarByClass(RetailDataAnalysis.class);
        job.setMapperClass(RetailDataAnalysisMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(RetailDataAnalysisReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(RetailDataAnalysisReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        for (int i = 0; i < otherArgs.length - 1; ++i) {
            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[i]));
        }
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[otherArgs.length - 1]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

Also if you are splitting the data by `,`, your data should be a csv, like this:

```
2012-01-01 09:20,Fort Worth,Women's Clothing,153.57,Visa
2012-01-01 09:00,San Jose,Mens Clothing,214.05,Rupee
2012-01-01 09:00,San Diego,Music,76.43,Amex
2012-01-01 09:00,New York,Cameras,5.76,Visa
```

Not space separated as you specified it in your question.

Comment: @Michel Lonski i tried your analysis but it did not helped me,one thing i am not getting ,when i am using Text key then also from where it is getting the LongWritable Instance

Comment: You need also to change the mapper key type. I edited my answer and pasted whole code that I tested.

Comment: Yes, it does. It doesn't on yours?

Comment: got the difference i will test it and surely let you know , thanks for  the help

Comment: getting this error Error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
 at com.df.wc.RetailDataAnalysis$RetailDataAnalysisMapper.map(RetailDataAnalysis.java:25)
 at com.df.wc.RetailDataAnalysis$RetailDataAnalysisMapper.map(RetailDataAnalysis.java:1)  with the same data set you have given

Comment: So it is not the same data. You probably added header, empty line or something. You can debug it easily. I did not refactor your code, it does not do any checking. I only switched the key type.

Answer (score 0):

When you read a file using Map Reduce, the file input format ( the default one ) reads an entire line and sends it to the mapper in the format of  , so the input to the mapper becomes :-

```
public static class RetailDataAnalysisMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,Text>
```

In case you need to read as

```
public static class RetailDataAnalysisMapper extends Mapper<Text,Text,Text,Text>
```

you would need to change the file input format and use your custom file input format  along with the custom record reader.
Then you need to add the following line in the driver code.

```
job.setInputFormatClass("your custom input format".class);
```

Hadoop understands everything in the form of  
so when you read a file, the offset becomes the LongWritable key and the value read becomes the value. 
So you need to use the default signature of `Mapper<LongWritable,Text, <anything>,<anything> >`

Comment: Rami tried your analysis but it did not helped me,one thing i am not getting ,when i am using Text key then also from where it is getting the LongWritable Instance

Comment: Hadoop understands everything in the form of <Key,Value> so when you read a file, the offset becomes the LongWritable key and the value read becomes the value.